# MudSelect Issue in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am new on Blazor WASM and I am working on a project that uses MudBlazor. But, I have a problem with MudSelect. I want to display the department's name in MudSelect. However, I need to bind `DepartmentID`. The code that below works partially, though when I want to edit a personal, just showing `DepartmentID`. It is not converted to department name but when I click the screen it turns `DepatmentName`.

Where am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<MudSelect @bind-Value="personal.DepartmentID" Label="Select Department"  Variant="Variant.Outlined"  OffsetY="true">

    @foreach (var department in departments){
          <MudSelectItem  Value="@(department.DepartmentID)">@item.DepartmentName</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
```

@Code Section

```
@code{
     [Parameter] public List<Department> departments { get; set; } = new List<Department>();

      protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
      {
            departments = await departmentRepository.GetDepartment();
      }
}
```

Repository

```
    public async Task<List<Department>> GetDepartment()
    {
        var response = await httpService.Get<List<Department>>(url);
        
        if (!response.Success)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(await response.GetBody());
        }

        return response.Response;   
    }
```

Controller

```
   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Department>>> Get() 
    {
        return  await context.Departments.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: can you please share your `@code` section?

Comment: You code shows displaying `@item.DepartmentName`, but your value references `@(department.DepartmentID)`.  What is `item`?  Surely you should be displaying `@department.DepartmentName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `Department` as value of your MudSelect. All you need to do is to make sure that the Department class has suitable equality overrides. I created a working demo which you can execute online at: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cEwFFmbgRxLbvVQg

```html
<MudSelect @bind-Value="_selectedDepartment" Label="Select Department"  Variant="Variant.Outlined"  OffsetY="true">

    @foreach (var department in departments){
          <MudSelectItem  Value="@department">@department.DepartmentName</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
<br/><br/>
Selected Department: @_selectedDepartment?.DepartmentName

@code {
    Department _selectedDepartment;

    IEnumerable<Department> departments = new List<Department>()
    {
        new Department() {DepartmentID = 1, DepartmentName = "Biology"},
        new Department() {DepartmentID = 2, DepartmentName = "Physics"},
        new Department() {DepartmentID = 3, DepartmentName = "Chemistry"},
        new Department() {DepartmentID = 4, DepartmentName = "Mathematics"},
        new Department() {DepartmentID = 5, DepartmentName = "Law"},
        new Department() {DepartmentID = 6, DepartmentName = "Sociology"}
    };

    public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public override bool Equals(object o) {
            var other = o as Department;
            return other?.DepartmentID==DepartmentID;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode() => DepartmentID.GetHashCode();        
        public override string ToString() {
            return DepartmentName;
        }
    }
}
```